# Microsoft Graph People API - error in get request /me/people/{id}

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-people

I can get list of people most relevant to me by /me/people,
from that list if I want to get a particular user by its id using /users/{id} then its not working.

I get internal server error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "daecb2b5-946f-48e9-8b44-11a8e593e768",
            "date": "2018-05-09T01:58:34"
        }
    }
}
```

FYI I am firing API call [as documented here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/person_get)

Comment: This looks like a bug, I've filed an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2622) to surface it with the Graph team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who comes looking for an answer here-

As per Microsoft, this was never intended to work, This is just an error in the documentation. Relevant docs have been modified.